# Which php version does the cakephp 1.3.2 support? Our team wanted to use php 5.6

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, lamp

Right now, our team want to upgrade cakephp from 1.2 to 1.3.2, and we also want to upgrade the php version to 5.6. Does it work? The cakephp 1.3.2 will support the php 5.6?

Comment: so cackephp has no documentation ?

Comment: You know, it's strange to upgrade to 1.3.2(last commit 3 years ago) when there exists 3.0.0-beta.

Comment: Because it is my company business choice. I just did it based on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The required PHP version is: **PHP 4.3.2 or greater**

Please see the official site to see any other requirement: http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/The-Manual/Developing-with-CakePHP/Requirements.html

Comment: ok,thank you. I install the cakephp 1.3.20 and php 5.6, then made a small app on it. It worked successfully.